# How can I create a Swift Combine publisher from two publishers A and B where publisher B consumes the value from publisher A?

Tags: swift, combine, userdefaults, grdb, grdbcombine

I want to create a Swift Combine publisher which achieves the following:

- The publisher should be triggered by changes in *either* [Defaults](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Defaults#observe-changes-to-a-key) (a `UserDefaults` Swift package) *or* changes in GRDB sqlite database values (using [GRDBCombine](https://github.com/groue/GRDBCombine#database-observation)).
- The updated `UserDefaults` received from the [Defaults](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Defaults#observe-changes-to-a-key) publisher should be used *within* the database query in the [GRDBCombine](https://github.com/groue/GRDBCombine#database-observation) publisher.

Here is a simplified version of what I have tried so far:

```
func tasksPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<[Task], Never> {
    Defaults.publisher(.myUserDefault)
        .flatMap { change in
            let myUserDefault = change.newValue

            return ValueObservation
                .tracking { db in
                    try Task.
                        .someFilter(myUserDefault)
                        .fetchAll(db)
                }
                .removeDuplicates()
                .publisher(in: database)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

However, this publisher produces the following error (edited according to the simplified version of my publisher above):

> `Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<Publishers.FlatMap<_, AnyPublisher<Defaults.KeyChange<Int>, Never>>.Output, Publishers.FlatMap<_, AnyPublisher<Defaults.KeyChange<Int>, Never>>.Failure>' (aka 'AnyPublisher<_.Output, Never>') to return type 'AnyPublisher<[Task], Never>'`

My bet is that there is a problem with the two publishers having different values: `[Task]` and `Defaults.KeyChange<Int>`. However, I cannot find a way to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to start a new database publisher each time the Defaults publisher emits a change, you need the [switchToLatest()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204759-switchtolatest) operator.

This operator needs errors from both publishers to be harmonized. Here, since Defaults.publisher has the `Never` failure type, we can use the [setFailureType(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204753-setfailuretype) operator in order to converge on the database publisher failure type: `Error`.

This gives:

```
func tasksPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<[Task], Error> {
    Defaults
        .publisher(.myUserDefault)
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .map({ change -> DatabasePublishers.Value<[Task]> in
            let myUserDefault = change.newValue
            return ValueObservation
                .tracking { db in
                    try Task
                        .someFilter(myUserDefault)
                        .fetchAll(db)
                }
                .removeDuplicates()
                .publisher(in: database)
        })
        .switchToLatest()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Note that the returned publisher has the `Error` failure type, because the database is not 100% reliable, as all I/O externalities. It is difficult, in a Stack Overflow answer, to recommend hiding errors at this point (by turning them into an empty Task array, for example), because hiding errors prevents your app from knowing what's wrong and react accordingly.

Yet here is a version below that traps on database errors. This is the version I would use, assuming the app just can't run when SQLite does not work: it's sometimes useless to pretend such low-level errors can be caught and processed in a user-friendly way.

```
// Traps on database error
func tasksPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<[Task], Never> {
    Defaults
        .publisher(.myUserDefault)
        .map({ change -> AnyPublisher<[Task], Never> in
            let myUserDefault = change.newValue
            return ValueObservation
                .tracking { db in
                    try Task
                        .someFilter(myUserDefault)
                        .fetchAll(db)
                }
                .removeDuplicates()
                .publisher(in: database)
                .assertNoFailure("Unexpected database failure")
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        })
        .switchToLatest()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a great solution! However, `switchToLatest()` returns `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. But it worked perfectly without it. Regarding the error handeling you suggested: Is the purpose the same as [this line](https://github.com/groue/GRDBCombine/blob/1217e8735fbf352343ee8944dce693eabeb967d3/Documentation/Demo/GRDBCombineDemo/UI/HallOfFameViewModel.swift#L14) `.catch { _ in Empty() }` in GRDBCombine's demo app?

Comment: The sample codes I provide above do compile with Xcode 11.4, so I can't help regarding your `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` error. This is a not a question about the Swift compiler, after all. Yes, I guess the `.catch { _ in Empty() }` plays the same role. Do not copy blindly: you have to figure out what your app needs first, evaluate your options, and write the code that expresses your intent. It takes time, but it's worth it.

Comment: But shouldn't the absence of `switchToLatest()` result in some problems here, since we have two publishers in one?